# Why the Background Color is not shown behind the Paragraph in the container sitetitle

Tags: php, html, css

im a little bit lost in my learning progress.
Thise is a peace of my php Site

```
<dev class="sitetitle">
<dev class="sitetitle-text">
    <p>
        Wir bieten
        <?php
        $welcomewords = array(
            "Walkinggruppen", "Selbstverteidigungskurse", "Ganzkörperworkouts", "Aquafitness", "Mitterkindkurse", "Rehasport", "Fitness"
        );
        echo $welcomewords[array_rand($welcomewords)]
        ?>

    </p>
</dev>
```

and that is the css:

```
.news{
background-color: #34495e;
}
.sitetitle{
    color: rgb(209, 195, 0);
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: #718daa;
    background-position: center;
    
}
```

so i want to create a backgound for the rotating text. It shoud be from right to left and the text stand on it. Threre also should be a magin in the hight of, let us say 400p. You can see that I want to set a banner there. I pressenting the high quality draft XD.
[Best Draft of the Century](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crUuG.png)
I think it can be helpful if i Post the Complete Code in the end.

```css
.news {
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.sitetitle {
  color: rgb(209, 195, 0);
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: #718daa;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Hier fängt die Navbar an */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

h2,
h3,
a {
  color: #34495e;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.45em;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.logo a,
.main-nav a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: .99em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.header {
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* ================================= 
      Media Queries
    ==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}


/* und hier endet sie */
```

```html
<html>

<head lang="de">
  <title>Start [Gymnastikriege Dedenbach]</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">GR#Dedenbach</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anmelden</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <dev class="sitetitle">
    <dev class="sitetitle-text">
      <p>
        Wir bieten
        <?php
                    $welcomewords = array(
                        "Walkinggruppen", "Selbstverteidigungskurse", "Ganzkörperworkouts", "Aquafitness", "Mitterkindkurse", "Rehasport", "Fitness"
                    );
                    echo $welcomewords[array_rand($welcomewords)]
                    ?>

      </p>
    </dev>
  </dev>
  <dev class="sitecontent">
    <dev class="showroom">
      <p> ich bin der Showroom
        <p>
    </dev>
    <dev class="news">
      <p>Hier kommen "news"

    </dev>
  </dev>
</body>
```

thanks a lot for helping and i know my bad english skills, i'm currently working on it. But i's enough that my teacher bullys me. Wir können sonst auch sehr gerne mal Deutsch reden.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `div` and not `dev`.

```css
.news {
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.sitetitle {
  color: rgb(209, 195, 0);
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: #718daa;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Hier fängt die Navbar an */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

h2,
h3,
a {
  color: #34495e;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.45em;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.logo a,
.main-nav a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: .99em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.header {
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* ================================= 
      Media Queries
    ==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}


/* und hier endet sie */
```

```html
<html>

<head lang="de">
  <title>Start [Gymnastikriege Dedenbach]</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">GR#Dedenbach</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Anmelden</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="sitetitle">
    <div class="sitetitle-text">
      <p>
        Wir bieten
        <?php
                    $welcomewords = array(
                        "Walkinggruppen", "Selbstverteidigungskurse", "Ganzkörperworkouts", "Aquafitness", "Mitterkindkurse", "Rehasport", "Fitness"
                    );
                    echo $welcomewords[array_rand($welcomewords)]
                    ?>

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sitecontent">
    <div class="showroom">
      <p> ich bin der Showroom
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
      <p>Hier kommen "news"

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh damm, one charakter div and dev. Thank you it works :) Have a nice evening